# Matching Delphi code template only at begin of line

Tags: templates, delphi

I want to create a code template that only matches a name if it is right at the beginning of the line. This way using "sum" as the name of the template for a documentation `<summary>` block doesn't get in conflict with creating a variable named `sum` as a variable never starts at the beginning of a line (at least in my coding style).

I already tried the following:

```
    <template name="&#13;&#10;sum" invoke="auto">
```

and

```
    <template name="\r\nsum" invoke="auto">
```

Both didn't work: The first didn't match at all, the second matches literally to what you see here.

Is this even possible?

P.S.
Just tried this (thanks HeartWare):

```
    <template name="
sum" invoke="auto">
```

Didn't work either.

Comment: Just a wild, wild guess. Have you tried actually inserting a new line within the quoted name? Ie. not by symbols, but by actual characters?

Comment: @HeartWare - Good idea but no, didn't work. Just tried it.

Comment: I turn off auto complete for code templates and manually invoke them using CTRL+J to bring up a filtered list to select from. Never liked the random unintended template code explosions that the auto complete occasionally does.